# Mongo find query in batches

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

My aim is to query MongoDB from my spring boot application, such that the query results are processed in my application in batches, as it may run out of memory if the resultSet returned is too big.

```
public void process(String productId) {
        MongoIterable<MongoOrder> orders = getCollection().find(eq("product_id", productId)).batchSize(10000);
        while (orders.iterator().hasNext()) {
            // some processing
        }
    }

private MongoCollection<MongoOrder> getCollection() {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase()
                .getCollection("orders", MongoOrder.class);
    }
```

In this above code snippet, I am trying to query the Mongo collection in batches of 10k. Will this work, or, does this bring into memory all the matching objects and then processes it one by one?

Had this been SQL, I would have queried with limits like `LIMIT 0, 10000`, then `LIMIT 10000, 10000` and so on. I want to do a similar thing here, with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should work:

```
public void process(String productId) {
        int offset = 10000;
        int curr = 0;
        List<MongoOrder> orders = StreamSupport.stream(getCollection().find(eq("product_id", productId)).skip(curr).limit(offset).spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
        while (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(orders)) {
            // some processing
            curr += offset;
            orders = StreamSupport.stream(getCollection().find(eq("product_id", productId)).skip(curr).limit(offset).spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Here, we are querying mongo in batches of 10k, and our application will also bring into memory only 10k objects at a time, thereby, not having a situation wherein we will run out of heap memory.